# CMD/WMIC выбрать значения касающиеся только определенного процесса

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, devops

*Есть команда.*

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where Name='chrome' get PercentProcessorTime,IDProcess
```

Эта команда выдает список процессов и сколько этот процесс занимает процессора в процентах. Проблема заключается в том, что процессов chrome например может быть очень много и они нумеруются. Как получить все процессы например **chrome**. А не один.

*Нагуглил. Такое решение.*

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where (Name LIKE '%chrome%') get Name,PercentProcessorTime,IDProcess
```

*Получил вывод.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема:** проблема заключается в том, что при запуске этой команды в **bat** падает ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно использование именно в bat файле. Для того чтобы получить список ID-шников и сколько занимает процессора каждый ID-шник. Для дальнейших манипуляций над этими процессами по id.

Comment: Во втором приложенном скриншоте Вы пытаетесь запросить информацию по пустому объекту - строка поиска то пустая: **(Name LIKE '')**. Если хотите вывести данные по всем процессам уберите из запроса конструкцию **where** или задайте в строке маску: для подстановки произвольных символов в утилите wmic используется **знак процента**. Например, **(Name LIKE '%')**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне нужно вывести все процессы которые бы касались chrome например. Если вас не затруднит могли бы вы показать пример.

Comment: Думаю нужен аналог chrome*

Comment: Я не понял вопроса. Подходящая Вам команда и так описана в  примере: **wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where (Name like 'chrome%') get PercentProcessorTime,IDProcess**. Что Вас не устраивает?

Comment: В .bat эта команда работать как нужно не будет.

Comment: А что именно не работает в вызове этой команды из бат-файла?

Comment: Выводится только один процесс.

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что Вы не учитываете особенность использования спецсимволов. В командной строке % - просто символ. В батнике же - это директива для поиска переменной. Чтобы обработка команды прошла нормально, укажите явно, что будет использован знак процента с помощью удвоения. В данном случае так: **wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where (Name LIKE '%chrome%%') get Name,PercentProcessorTime,IDProcess**

Comment: Результат выполнения батника с двумя знаками процента. http://prntscr.com/haekki

Comment: мой косяк - лишний знак вставил. Должно быть: **wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process where (Name LIKE 'chrome%%') get Name,PercentProcessorTime,IDProcess**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Также можно использовать команду

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime /format:csv | find "chrome"
```

Answer (score -1):

Решение проблемы.

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process get Name,PercentProcessorTime,IDProcess | findstr /i /c:chrome
```